# Can I Firebase createUser with an arbitrary ID instead of an email address

Tags: authentication, firebase

I'm using Firebase for an Atlassian Connect AddOn. I want to use Firebase users to secure the data.

The users will be identified by a clientKey provided by Atlassian (probably after I fudge it a bit) - NOT BY EMAIL.

Ideally, I don't want to have to do my own authentication here, as the Firebase.createUser method would suffice entirely if I could provide something other than an email to it, but I can't find anything like that in the documentation.

Is there a way I can create Firebase users WITHOUT AN EMAIL (just an ID and password), without going to all the way into oAuth and all that jargon to create my own custom authentication?

Comment: Instead of double-authenticating and duct taping the two together--an approach that is bound to cause endless pain--the best solution would be to just [generate Firebase tokens](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/custom.html) from the Atlassian ids. You can add the clientKey into the token and use that to secure the data. It's going to be easier and happier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Firebase user must have an email. If that is a problem then we can't use a Firebase "user", but instead a "token" (which must have a UID as part of it's payload and hence behaves the same way in terms of security once it reaches their datastore).

If you don't need a password, then "instead of double-authenticating and duct taping" as @Kato kindly pointed out, you can generate your own Firebase tokens and serve them to the client.

If you require the user to provide a password then you'd have to implement your own verification before you generate the token and serve it to the client. Since there's no Firebase user involved anymore, but rather a token your privileged server can arbitrarily create and serve, it's your responsibility to ensure you're doing that at the right time (i.e. when a user has provided your server with an adequate ID and password).

Read more about [Custom Authentication here and tokens](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/custom.html).